# Making transform translate create problem

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
public GameObject teleportPoint_1;
public GameObject teleportPoint_2;

void Update(){
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D)) {
        transform.position = teleportPoint_1.transform.position;
        transform.rotation = teleportPoint_1.transform.rotation;

    }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
        transform.position = teleportPoint_2.transform.position;
        transform.rotation = teleportPoint_2.transform.rotation;
    }
```

Here are the transform values:

**teleportPoint_1**
Position = (0, 0.3 , 0.67)
Rotation = (-30, 0, 0)

**teleportPoint_2**
Transform = (0, 0.3 , -0.67)
Rotation = (30, 0, 0)

**GameObject**
Transform = (0, 2 , 0)
Rotation = (0, 0, 0)

Let's get to the problem. I have created these Game Objects so that when you press 'A' you get teleported to the first object (teleportPoint_1) and vice-versa for 'D'.

When I press 'A' once the new transform is as follows:
Transform = (0, 2.3 , 0.67)
Rotation = (-30, 0, 0)

This is not a problem, this is exactly what I want
But then when I press 'A' (editor: OP probably meant 'D') once again and here is the new transform:
Transform = (0, 2.2248 , 0.06)
Rotation = (0, 0, 0)

Why is the GameObject gliding by 0.06 on the Z-axis and why does it not return to the original Y coordinate (2)? I have tried adding a RigidBody and FreezeStats but they didn't solve the problem.

Can anobody help me? What is the problem and what is it exactly that I have to do?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to modify your transform rather than teleport to the targeted GameObject. You should increment the position and rotation of your GameObject rather than teleport to another one.

```
// Define the change in position and rotation
private Vector3 position_offset = new Vector3(0f, 0.3f, 0.67f);
private Vector3 rotation_offset = new Vector3(30f, 0f, 0f);

void Update()
{
    // If the 'A' key is pressed...
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
    {
        // Increment the rotation and rotation
        transform.position += position_offset;
        transform.eulerAngles += rotation_offset;
    }
    // If the 'D' key is pressed...
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
    {
        // Decrement the position and rotation
        transform.position -= position_offset;
        transform.eulerAngles -= rotation_offset;
    }
}
```

Tip: Instead of having 2 if statements, try using `Input.GetAxisRaw('Horizontal')` and adjusting the offset using the returned value.

Comment: Comment: `Time.deltaTime` is not needed since the code only runs once when the key is down instead of multiple times while the key is pressed.